# How to Enable Virtualization within BIOS Version: IBM 2EKT37AUS 06/13/2006

Tags: cpu, bios, 64-bit, virtualization

I had try to install 64-bit OS *(Windows)*, after upgrade my RAM to *4GB*, but I got this message.

> ### Windows Boot Manager
>
> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be
>   the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click 'Next."
> 3. Click "Repair your computer."
>
> If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or
>   computer manufacture fro assistance.
>
> File: **\windows\system32\boot\winload.exe**
>
> Status: **0xc000035a**
>
> Info: **Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is
>   not compatible with 64-bit mode.**

So I searched about it, and found that's mean I have to Enable **Virtualization** in **BIOS**, but unfortunately i don't know how to do it, with my machine:

> ### Lenovo ThinkCentre MT-M 8115-D37
>
> - Machine Type: **8115** Model: **D73**
> - CPU Type: **Intel (R) Pentium (R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz**
> - CPU Bus Speed: **800 MHz**
> - BIOS Version: **IBM 2EKT37AUS 06/13/2006**
> - Video Active: **Intel (r) 82945G Chipset Family Graphics Chip Accelerate**
> - Screens: **Setup Utility**
>
>   - [Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gt7p.jpg)
>   - [Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExzTG.jpg)

Comment: This is entirely unrelated to virtualization. Don’t know how you arrived at this conclusion. The reason is simple: You do not have a 64-bit CPU. Please provide the exact Lenovo product code and/or the exact CPU model name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I searched about it, and found that's mean I have to Enable Virtualization in BIOS, but unfortunately i don't know how to do it, with my machine:

Your CPU doesn't support VT-x so it's not possible to enable it.  You will be unable to install a 64-bit guest
operating system on the host machine your using.  You should have no problem installing a 32-bit guest operating system on the virtual machine

> I had try to install 64-bit OS (Windows), after upgrade my RAM to 4GB, but I got this message.

Of course your processor also doesn't support the 64-bit x86 extension either this means it's not possible to install a 64-bit host operating system either on the machine.

If you need a 64-bit operating system then upgrade from decade old hardware

> - Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x): No
> - Intel® 64: No
> - Instruction Set: 32-bit

[Source](http://ark.intel.com/m/products/27497/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-supporting-HT-Technology-3_00-GHz-1M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB)

Comment: Thanks.. am gonna change my processor to something in Intel Core 2 Duo family.

Comment: You will have to upgrade the motherboard if you do that.  But Core Duo is still a decade old.